# filter df by index location and comparison operator

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a df by subsetting values less that have a float value of less than `1.0` for the last two columns.

```
b = np.array([[10.0,2.0,3.0,7.0], [10.0,99.0,20.0,63.0], [0.5,99.0,20.0,63.0] ])

df = pd.DataFrame(b.T) 

cols = df.iloc[:,-2:].columns.values

df = df[df[cols] < 1.0]
```

Out:

```
    0   1    2
0 NaN NaN  0.5
1 NaN NaN  NaN
2 NaN NaN  NaN
3 NaN NaN  NaN
```

Intended:

```
     0    1    2
0 10.0 10.0  0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df[df[cols].le(1).any(axis=1)]
```